# How to access the value of 1st key of all the dictionaries saved as a list for a key in JSON using PYTHON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have the JSON which looks like this:-

```
{
        "name": "PT",
        "batservers": [
            {"name": "bat1", "qmchannel": "abcd", "mount": "efgh"},
            {"name": "bat2", "qmchannel": "abcd", "mount": "efgh"},
            {"name": "bat3", "qmchannel": "abcd", "mount": "efgh"},
        ]
    }
```

I want to retrieve the value of "name" present in all the dictionary and save it in a list variable i.e. ["bat1","bat2","bat3"]

I tried something like this:-

```
batsList = env["batservers"][0:]["name"]
```

but it displays the below error:-

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I know I can do this using a loop but can someone please help me to do using in a single line code way which I am trying above?

Thanks,
SUYASH GUPTA.

Comment: What do you expect `[0:]` this to do? you cannot access elements of a list with string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without a loop. But the loop can be a list comprehension:

```
batsList = [b['name'] for b in env["batservers"]
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the clarification. I'll try this. I thought we could do this if something like this env["batservers"][0]["name"] is allowed. We can access all elements of a list like print(a[0:]), but apparently by responses to my question, I cant merge both like env["batservers"][0:]["name"]. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

How about saving the list as:

list_of_names = [x[name] for x in env["batservers"]]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[b['name'] for b in env['batservers']]
```

Or this:

```
map(lambda b: b['name'], env['batservers'])
```

`[0:]` doesn't do much for you: it returns the same array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

`env["batservers"][0:]` returns a list, and you can't access directly the values of the dicts in the list.

You can use a list comprehension:

```
names = [elem["name"] for elem in env["batservers"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic solution using a for loop to iterate over the sub [**dictionary**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and appending to the empty [**list**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) `res`.

```
res = []
for item in env["batservers"]:
  res.append(item["name"])

print (res) #=> ['bat1', 'bat2', 'bat3']
```